# continue looping after alert message

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the function use to check for the session of my page. The page will reload after I clicked the alert message.

```
var timeleft = 60;

function checkTime() {
    timeLeft--;

    if (timeLeft == 30 ) 
    {
        alert("30 secs left.");
        window.location.reload();
    }

}
```

Is there anyway that the timeleft continue minus (if the user din't not notice the alert message) so that it will redirect to logout page when the timeleft is = 0.

Comment: `setTimeout(checkTime, 1000)`?

Comment: save timeLeft in the localstorage just before reload(), then load it from there in place of the first assignment

Comment: please clarify what is your question?? is it capturing the (timeleft) after the reload?? or you are facing problem with alert message?? your question is ambiguous to some extent :)

Comment: sorry for that. my question is there is 60 secs for a session, when it reach to 30 sec the alert message will popup to user whether he/she want to refresh it or not. My case was if the user is away from the computer, the session will still running until the session end and it redirect to logout page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alert()` is a modal, it stops javascript execution. Check this code:

```
var start = new Date();
var start2;
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var end = new Date();
    var result = "time from start: " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime())
    result += "\ntime from alert: " + (end.getTime() - start2.getTime())
    result += "\nalert was open for: " + (start2.getTime() - start.getTime())
    alert(result);
}, 500);
window.setTimeout(function() {
    alert("hello");
    start2 = new Date();
}, 100);
```

Fiddle for upper code: http://jsfiddle.net/aorcsik/vfeH2/1/

Check out this code, it shows that even setTimeout is stopped during `alert()`, but you can check how much time the user was looking at the alert, and update your counter (`timeLeft`) by decreasing with the measured time devided by your ticker delay.

**Solution:** So my solution would be to measure how much time the user looks at the alert modal, and whenever he clicks ok, check if his session ended, if yes redirect to logout, else do the usual redirect.

```
var start = new Date();
alert("xxx");
var t = (new Date()).getDate() - start.getDate();
if (t / 1000 > timeLeft) {
    /* logout */
} else {
    /* redirect */
}
```

**Note:** another solution would be to use some html popup instead of the javascript alert, which would not block javascript execution

Comment: i think he misrepresented his question: he want to reload the page while keeping the counter to the value it reach before reload !!

Comment: No I think I did not misunderstood, he wants the user to be logged out even if the user did not notice/click the alert.

Comment: regardless of the fact that alert is Modal or the user did notice or didn't notice the alert msg .. in his code the page will reload after the alert; then the timeleft will start from 60; and the user will never logout :(

Comment: @stackunderflow that is why I suggested a change, that instead of redirecting right after alert, check if the user has time left, and if not then logout

Comment: 1+ for your last suggestion html popup

Answer (score 2):

If you want an async alert you can try this

```
setTimeout(function() { alert('30 secs left'); }, 1);
```

But if you want a timed logout you can do something like this instead:

```
function checkTime() {
    setInterval(function(){alert("30 secs left.")},30000); // shown at 30 seconds
    setInterval(function(){logout()},60000); // called at 60 seconds
}

function logout() {
    // logout functionality
}
```

Comment: neat. simple and effective (Y)

Comment: +1 for the two setIntervals functions .... my wounder is : if the user didn't click ok on the alert message?? would the page logout ??

Answer (score 1):

your code comment is strange 
first you are using a number (60) and you consider it as (two minutes) then alert it is(30 seconds left)..

Anyways .. 
you want to count down and when there is only 30 seconds left you want to reload the page!!

the problem here is that when you reload the page you will reset the count down from (60 as in your code)

the solution is one of the following:
1- save the countdown in localstorage as pointed out by @Fabrizio  and when the page is reloaded again then use the saved counterdown value.
however this solution assume that your user browser can save to localstorage

2- second solution is that you post your page with the countdown and reload it with the count down..
let us say that you page address is: www.myexampleaddress.com/mypage
then you call the address as follow :www.myexampleaddress.com/mypage?timeleft=30

and catch this on the server and reload the page from the server with value in your querystring ..

so your coude after the alert should be like this

```
var myURL = location.href+'?timeleft=30';
location.href =myURL;
```

i hope that help :)